# How can we adjust this code to prevent the action of opening a new browser tab from executing the function called 'fetchRecommendations?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The 'getRecommendations' function contains some logic to filter out domains that don't match any of those in the competitors array. If there's a match between the current domain and the array, then 'fetchRecommendations' is executed. If no match, we return.

It's working correctly when I navigate to a non-competitor domain--fetchRecommendations is not called; but when I open a new tab (even if there's no url), fetchRecommendations is still executing. I'm unsure if this is because it's blank tab that the logic doesn't filter it out.  'getRecommendations' is called from another function called 'fetchBrandData.' I'm not positive if you need to see this, but I included it because I have a feeling it's connected with the action of opening a tab (I didn't write the code, so not positive)

My question is, why isn't 'getRecommendations' working to prevent 'fetchRecommendations' from executing for a blank url tab?: ]

Below is getRecommendations, followed by fetchRecommendations.

```
  export const getRecommendations = url => { 
         if (url === undefined || url === null) {
            return "";
          }
        
          return browser.storage.local.get("competitors").then(({ competitors }) => {
            // parse the domain from the URL
            const domain = parseDomain(url);
        
            const competitor = competitors.find(competitor => competitor.includes(domain));
            if (competitor) {
              console.log("Competitor match found: " + competitor);
              // domain is a competitor so perform request
              return fetchRecommendations(url); 
              
            } else {
              console.log("No competitor found for " + url);
              return "";
   }
  });
}

 export const fetchRecommendations = url =>
  browser.storage.local.get("user").then(({ user }) =>
    fetch(trestle.api.recommendations, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ currentUrl: url, emailAddress: user.username }),
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(recommendation => recommendation)
      .catch(e => new Error("Unable to return recommendations for company"))
  );
```

Here is fetchBrandData, from which getRecommendations is called:

```
 export const fetchBrandData = tab =>
      Promise.all([getBrandByUrl(tab.url), getRecommendations(tab.url)]).then(
        values => {
          const [brand, recommendation] = values;
          const { hasRecommendations, hasMatchScore } = recommendation;
    
          browser.storage.local
            .get(["popupClosedByUser", "alarms"])
            .then(({ popupClosedByUser, alarms = {} }) => {
              // if there's any recommendations, sort them by the highest Trestle score
              if (hasRecommendations) {
                recommendation.recommendations = sortByKey(
                  recommendation.recommendations,
                  "score"
                );
```

Comment: What is "blank url tab" exactly? Show us the real value. Is it `chrome://newtab`? Other than that I don't see anything suspicious or even relevant to tab opening in this code so I'd say it's impossible to answer as we don't see a real [MCVE](/help/mcve) here.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a bit of a guessing game for me as to what part of this project concerns the creation of a new browser tab, so this may very well not be right.  When I say blank tab, I mean opening a new tab in Chrome. For me, there is nothing in the address bar, so there's no domain to check against the competitors array. This is what I mean by 'blank'. It just shows no url at all.

Comment: The internal URL as reported by all extension API is `chrome://newtab/` so it's not blank.